# perl -p -i -e inside a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, docker

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/

rm index.php
cd modules/mymodules/

perl -p -i -e 's/x.xx.xx.y/dd.dd.ddd.dd/g' `grep -ril y.yy.yy.y *`
```

shows shows a warning

```
-i used with no filenames on the command line, reading from STDIN.
```

It prevents running rest of the scripts.

Any solutions ?

Actually I need to run

```
perl -p -i -e 's/x.xx.xx.y/dd.dd.ddd.dd/g' `grep -ril y.yy.yy.y *`
Inside a shell script
```

*I am using ubuntu with docker.*

Comment: Try to remove `-i` ?

Comment: Please try to narrow it down. Does it work outside of a shell script? If not, it's a problem the command and not with "perl -p -i -e inside a shell script"

Comment: `.` has a special meaning in regex patterns. I'm pretty sure `x.xx.xx.y` should be `x\.xx\.xx\.y`.

Comment: **First** Why are you using `grep` just for checking before **Perl** that wants to substitute your pattern? (= in place if `if`) |  **Second** `-i` is for **edit-in-place** and it needs a file name for getting a backup of your file: `-i.bck` and `i` here is the name of your input file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at this a step at a time. First, you're running this `grep` command:

```
grep -ril y.yy.yy.y *
```

This recursively searches all files and directories in your current directory. It looks for files containing the string "y.yy.yy.yy" in any case and returns a list of the files which contain this text.

This command will return either a list of filenames or nothing.

Whatever is returned from that `grep` command is then passed as arguments to your Perl command:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/x.xx.xx.y/dd.dd.ddd.dd/g' [list of filenames]
```

If `grep` returns a list of files, then the `-p` option here means that each line in every file in the list is (in turn) run through that substitution and then printed to a new file. The `-i` means there's one new file for each old file and the new files are given the same names as the old files (the old files are deleted once the command has run).

So far so good. But what happens if the `grep` doesn't return any filenames? In that case, your Perl command doesn't get any filenames and that would trigger the error that you are seeing.

So my (second) guess is that your `grep` command isn't doing what you want it to and is returning an empty list of filenames. Try running the `grep` command on its own and see what you get.

Comment: I don't see any data being piped to the `perl` command; rather I see an *expected* list of file names produced by the `grep` command, which may not produce any output.

Comment: @chepner: You're absolutely right, of course. See my update.

Comment: If it's possible for `grep` to return an empty list, you could use `grep -ril y.yy.yy.y * | xargs perl -pe's/x.xx.xx.y/dd.dd.ddd.dd/g'` or `find . -type f -exec perl -i -0777pe's/x.xx.xx.y/dd.dd.ddd.dd/g if /y\.yy\.yy\.y/i' {} +`